# Laravel nova diffForHumans DateTime

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have field last_active on users, I want display time with diffForHumans or `time_from_now` from Moment.js. How I can do it? Now I just use:

```
DateTime::make('Activiy', 'last_active')
            ->exceptOnForms(),
```

When I use:

```
DateTime::make('Activiy', 'last_active')->diffForHumans()
            ->exceptOnForms(),
```

I get undifined method `diffForHumans`.

Comment: Maybe you didn't cast the `last_active` column as datetime on your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge at the moment `DateTime` only supports `format`.

Since you want only to display, you can try `Text` field & display the humanise value. If your column might be null be sure to check for that otherwise you will get an error.

```
Text::make('Activiy', 'last_active')
    ->displayUsing(function($lastActive) {
        if ($lastActive === null) {
            return null;
        }
        return $lastActive->diffForHumans();
    })
    ->exceptOnForms(),
```